# rails 5 error with multiple models and additional fields with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using rails 5 and the devise gem to create different Models in my project.

Each model have additional fields, let's say User has a "username" field.

I followed the Devise instruction to add this fiel, I create a "user_sanitizer.rb" file in my lib folder with the following code :

```
class User::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def initialize(*)
    super
    permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email])
  end
end
```

My "application_controller.rb" looks like that :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protected

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == User
      User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
    else
      super # Use the default one
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I try to sign_up a new User I have this error :

```
uninitialized constant User::ParameterSanitizer
```

So I don't really know what to do to initialize it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, adding :

```
require 'user_sanitizer'
```

On top of my application controller.rb file.